# Is fixed-effects ordered logit models (feologit in Stata) suitable for matched case-control data?

Tags: ordinal-data, matching, latent-variable, ordered-logit, case-control-study

Does anyone happen to be familiar with this method: fixed-effects ordered logit models (feologit in Stata)? In this paper: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X20930984

In the paper, this method was applied to panel-data. Is the BUC-tau method also suitable for case-control data?

For example, two types of cases (hospitalization with complication, hospitalization without complication) are matched to one control (no hospitalization) respectively. I feel that the common odds ratio may be affected by the sampling rate of the cases and control but I am not sure.